# Override downloading a file type with Chrome Extensions

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to build a chrome extension that overrides a download of a file and displays it in the browser. For example if you click on a link to a '.csv' file I'd like it to render in the browser instead of downloading it.

Chrome already does it for PDF's types and the [Xml Tree extension also does exactly that for xml files.](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gbammbheopgpmaagmckhpjbfgdfkpadb)

So it should be possible, just not sure how to go about catching that event?

Comment: Not sure, but this may be relevant http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=35070
and
http://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/group/chromium-extensions/browse_thread/thread/a76cb5f021bbce7e/a1c439d747250170?lnk=gst&q=file+type#a1c439d747250170

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An implementation along the lines indicated by in the previous answers and specifically designed for CSV files can be found in this extension of mine on github:

https://github.com/rgrp/chrome-csv-viewer

Furthermore, with the new(ish) chrome [webrequest API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest.html) a direct approach is also now possible along the following lines:

1. Listen to onBeforeRequest (this has to be in a background script - see background.js)
2. Check if this is a CSV file (mimetype or file extension)
3. If so cancel the request and then display the data using xhr

A working version of this can be found in a branch of that extension: https://github.com/rgrp/chrome-csv-viewer/tree/4-webrequest-intercept

Answer (score 2):

You could always look at the XML Tree code :).

If you only need to work with links, and not opening files from the address bar or File > Open, you could build a content script that adds a click event listener to every link.

In the event listener function:

1. Add `e.preventDefault()` in the first line to prevent the browser 'following' the link.
2. Using the link href value, get the data with XMLHttpRequest.
3. In the XMLHttpRequest callback, open a new tab and render content accordingly.

Obviously, in many ways, this is not a great solution:

- you want 'normal' links to be handled as usual by the browser
- how can you tell if a text file contains comma-separated values (for example) except by looking at the file extension which, of course, may not be reliable?

Are you specifically thinking of .csv files -- and/or other specific types of content?